# How can I append to Java KeyEvent modifiers?

Tags: java, keyevent, modifiers

I have a KeyEvent whose modifiers I want to change to include the shift key. My current approach is to create a new KeyEvent using information from the old, attempting to add the shift key to the modifiers. However, it doesn't seem to be working.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
event = new KeyEvent((Component) event.getSource(), KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, event.getWhen(), event.getModifiersEx() | KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK, event.getKeyCode(), KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:
`event = new KeyEvent((Component) event.getSource(), KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, event.getWhen(), event.getModifiersEx() | KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK, event.getKeyCode(), KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED);`

I should have done this:
`event = new KeyEvent((Component) event.getSource(), event.getID(), event.getWhen(), event.getModifiersEx() | KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK, event.getKeyCode(), KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED);`

Note that instead of KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED I have event.getID().